How to ignore part of the JSON?
In the following JSON I want to ignore the first part.
JSON Example:
{
  "game": {
     "friends": 10,
      "worlds": 50,
  },
  "results": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Infantry",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "Cavalry",

  }
]

}
My model is:
struct Item {
  //MARK: Properties
  let id: Int
  let type: String
}

The decode method:
static var previewsFromJson: [Item] {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "apiData", withExtension: "json")
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)

   let items = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
   return items
   }
  

How can I decode only the result array?

You still need to decode the outer shape, but you can define it as just struct Container: Codable { results: [Item] } and ignore the other keys

Do not include anything you want to ignore in your model. Your model struct should be like this as @jnpdx mentioned in comments:
struct Container: Codable {
    let results: [Item]
    
    struct Item: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let type: String
    }
}

And replace [Item].self with Container.self.
let items = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Container.self, from: data)

Suggestion: Please, learn how to decode, start from the beginning. Do not rush. You could find an answer to this question in the books, tutorials, articles...

I know that way, but I wanted to know if there was a way not to create a Wrapper Struct. Similar to how it was done with JSONSerialization.

@ArielAntonioFundora There is no way, and with JSONSerialization you have to decode the JSON from the top as well respectively you have to get the value for key results.
